# C# Dictionary to Sorted JSON

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the C# web project (MVC4) that I need to get via an AJAX Call and return a jSON. This part is all good, but the returned data is sorted by the key of the dictionary. I can't find a way of sorting by the value. The complication is the value is an object consisting of a string and an int. So the structure is

```
<key, <object>>
```

where the object is a string, int

I can't change the structure of the dictionary as its used in other parts of the application on the page creation.

Any ideas of how I can accomplish this?

If not I'll rebuild the structure in the c# side of things.

Ta

Comment: You want to order by the string or by the int value of the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you have a class with an int and a string

```
public class MyObj 
{
    public int iValue { get; set; } 
    public string sValue { get; set; } 
}
```

You can sort a Dictionary by the value of the value:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, MyObj>();

var sortedKeyValuePair = dictionary.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.iValue).ToList();
```

The result is a `List < KeyValuePair < TKey, MyObj> >` ordered by the int value of your object.